# Query SQL Table with Value from MultipleSelectionComboBox

Tags: c#

So, I'm using Syncfusion controls and I've a MultipleSelectionCombobox where user can filter multiple arguments.

I have a query which will load a list based on parameters query.

So, first, I have a class to hold my values;

```
public class Orders
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNum { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the query:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> LoadData()
    {
        var ctx = new DbContext();
        var query = (from o in ctx.tblOrders.AsQueryable()
                     select new Orders
                     {
                         ID = o.OrderID,
                         OrderNum = o.OrderNum.ToString(),
                         Status = o.OrderStatus,
                         Date = o.OrderDate
                     });
        if(CmbOrderStatus.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (SelectedItems obj in CmbOrderStatus.SelectedItems)
            {
                list.Add(obj.ToString());
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = list[i];
                query = query.Where(p => p.Status == value);
            }
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

So, in Database in have many Orders and many OrderStatus, like "Opened", "Delayed", "Closed".

So, if I filter in CmbOrderStatus "Opened" and "Delayed", I get nothing! If only one is selected, I get nothing!

Any help here?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want something like SelectedItems Contains p.Status. Right now you are asking for Status that equals all selected items and that's impossible unless all selected items are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code use only last filter. 
Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> LoadData()
{
    var ctx = new DbContext();
    var query = (from o in ctx.tblOrders.AsQueryable()
                 select new Orders
                 {
                     ID = o.OrderID,
                     OrderNum = o.OrderNum.ToString(),
                     Status = o.OrderStatus,
                     Date = o.OrderDate
                 });
    if(CmbOrderStatus.SelectedItems != null)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (SelectedItems obj in CmbOrderStatus.SelectedItems)
        {
            list.Add(obj.ToString());
        }

        query = query.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Status));            
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This may work but it is incorrect to say the code only uses the last filter. They are cummulative, but obviously a string cannot equal more than one different string.